# Sample operator with repetition

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I would like an equivalent to the sample operator that does not implicitly filter its results stream to be distinct:

```
var ints = new Subject<int>();
var pulse = new Subject<Unit>();

ints.Sample(pulse)
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

ints.OnNext(1);
pulse.OnNext(Unit.Default);
ints.OnNext(2);
pulse.OnNext(Unit.Default);
pulse.OnNext(Unit.Default);
ints.OnNext(3);

// Prints 1, 2 instead of 1, 2, 2
```

My attempt at a join worked for the above example but failed in other cases (on hot observables):

```
public static IObservable<TIn> SampleWithRepetition<TIn, TPulse>(this IObservable<TIn> source, IObservable<TPulse> pulse)
{
    return from x in source
           join _ in pulse on source equals Observable.Empty<Unit>()
           select x;
}
```

Is it possible to define such an operator without using a state-based `Observable.Create` method?

Comment: Please provide reasons for downvotes

Comment: Drive-by downvoting? What's the issue?

Comment: Your question doesn't show any understanding of the problem you're trying to solve, nor any effort from your side that you spent to solve it. Just code and "how to fix it".

Comment: Fair - I've edited the question to be more specific

Comment: I'm confused by the fixation on "state-based" vs "functional".  The algorithm you are interested in requires state (it must remember the last value seen from the source so that it can be given out on each pulse).  If you were to find a way to chain together existing Rx operators that do what you want (instead of using `Create`) then it is only because one or more of those operators used `Create` (or the Rx internal analog to create) to define the state.

Comment: Yes, but as you saw from my answer which was not thread-safe before your comment, using existing Rx operators is an easier way to ensure correctness

Answer (score 2):

The following operator is state-based; there may be a more functional approach

```
public static IObservable<TIn> SampleWithRepetition<TIn, TPulse>(this IObservable<TIn> source, IObservable<TPulse> pulse)
{
    return Observable.Create<TIn>(obs =>
        {
            var gate = new object();
            var x = new {Value = default(TIn), HasValue = false};

            return new CompositeDisposable()
                {
                    source.Subscribe(
                        y =>
                            {
                                lock (gate)
                                    x = new {Value = y, HasValue = true};
                            },
                        obs.OnError,
                        obs.OnCompleted),

                    pulse.Subscribe(
                        _ =>
                            {
                                bool hasValue = false;
                                TIn value = default(TIn);
                                lock (gate)
                                {
                                    hasValue = x.HasValue;
                                    value = x.Value;
                                }
                                if (hasValue)
                                    obs.OnNext(value);
                            },
                        obs.OnError,
                        obs.OnCompleted)
                };
        });
}
```

}

Comment: your code has possible reads of half-written structs if source and pulse both produce a value at roughly the same time.  you'll need to put a lock around your use of `x` to avoid trouble.

Comment: Thanks - can I ask if you know of any good resources to learn about concurrency in RX? You seem to be very knowledgeable of it!

Comment: Read the Rx Design Guidelines if you haven't already: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2010/10/28/rx-design-guidelines.aspx for threading guarantees made by Rx and required by consumers.  Otherwise, just remember each observable you have might be signalling on a different thread so when manually listening to multiple observables you have to keep your usual multi-threaded hat on.  What makes Rx so useful is all of their operators do this for you, so usually you just use `Merge` or `Sample` and need not worry about it except when you need to write a new operator.

Comment: you can reduce lock contention quite a bit in your pulse onNext handler: { bool hasValue = false; T value = default(T); lock (gate) { if (x.HasValue) { hasValue = true; value = x.Value; } } if (hasValue) { obs.OnNext(value); }  That way the source is free to continue producing new values while your observer is observing the current value.

Comment: That looks like a fantastic resource, thanks. I've updated the method as per your recommendation too